# Using a custom font for underline with a fallback. [CSS only is possible]

Tags: css, font-face, underline, fallback

For an upcoming project we intend to use a font that has a custom drawn underline version. The underlining will be used to help the user to navigate the information.

I was thinking if there is any way to create a fallback solution where if the `@font-face` fails to load or is unsupported it can fall back on a system font with eg. `text-decoration`. But not have that applied to the `@font-face` font.

**Example**

> `<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor <span class="underline">set amet sector</span></h1>`
>
> In this case if it loaded the `@font-face` underline version succesfully the class uses that, if not and only if not `text-decoration : underline` is added.

It shouldn't be too complicated to detect this with JS but I'm curious if there's a way to solve this purely with CSS.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think so. CSS can't detect anything so it wouldn't "know" the font hasn't loaded.